# How to go to first screen of application?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to make a button, when I click this button, my application go to first screen.
My application used a lot of ways to go to screen (PageViewController, Push Navigation, present modal, ...).
Is there anyway to force switch to first screen and release all loaded screens?

Comment: Look up unwind segues.

Comment: Look at siba prasad Hotas answer

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Thank you, I resolved my problems with unwind segues

Answer (score 2):

```
UINavigationController* navController = self.navigationController;  
NSArray *viewControllers=[navController viewControllers];
UIViewController* controller = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
[navController popToViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go to the first page with the `popToRootViewControllerAnimated` method of  `UINavigationController`, if you didn't check root view inside your application.

Comment: Not easy poptorootview, my app used many ways.First used pageviewer, then used modal view and then used push navigation

Answer (score 1):

You could use unwind segues to do this or you can go back by instantiating your first view controller.(will not look like `pop` though.)

```
var firstVC: UIViewController? = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("firstVC") as?    UIViewController

self.presentViewController(firstVC!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

To go to first screen, you will have to initialise the first view controller of the app, set it as navigation controller's root view controller and then pop it over. Below is the code for same.

```
AppDelegate *appdelegate = ((AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate])  

ViewController *vc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:NULL] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"vc_id"];  
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: vc];
        [appdelegate.window setRootViewController:nav];
        [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

No matter, whatever is your stack and flow, the above code will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Function to load first screen on `Appdelegate` and call it on button click. In this case the `rootViewController` will be assigned to different object which will `deallocate` the other objects.

```
-(void)GotoFirstScreen:(UIViewController *)currentScreen {
    [currentScreen.view removeFromSuperview];
    MYFirstViewController *splsh     = [[MYFirstViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MYFirstViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *newVc   = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:splsh];
    newVc.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    self.window.rootViewController  = newVc;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Now call this method in this way

```
-(IBAction)ButtonClicked:(id)sender{
   AppDelegate *appdelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 
   [appdelegate GotoFirstScreen:self];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think in your case you want to load your first view after logging out from your app right..?

If this is the case then here is the solution for you. Below solution will load the first view from anywhere inside your app and will release almost all the scene and memory. However if you are using some NSUserDefaults or Appdelegate stuff to store the data, then you need to forcefully clear those objects to release their values.

This solution is in Swift but anyone can make the same thing in objective c also.

Now, jumping to the solution --

Step 1.
  Goto your storyborad and navigate to your desired viewcontroller which you wanna load as the first view.

Step 2. 
  Give some storyboard id to that viewcontroller.

Step 3.
  Use the below code on any button click or something's action dude.....and Voila!!!!...Its done. N.B. - Make an object of your appdelegate class inside the present class from where you wanna load the page.

By the way I am pasting an image about how to give the storyboard id to a viewcontroller which I think will help you a bit.

[image]

Now the code part --

```
      let appDelegateObjectForThisClass = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate //Creating Appdelegate Object.

@IBAction func LogOutSection(sender: AnyObject) { //Action of logout button
    self.appDelegateObjectForThisClass.window?.rootViewController = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("mainPage") //"Main" is the storyboard name here in my case, replace with yours. "mainPage" is your given storyboard id to that viewcontroller.
   }
```